# List is returning one after clearing all the items by deleting

Tags: java, android

My List is returning an item after clearing all the items by deleting ,On app fresh install its returing null which is good but after adding item and then by deleting all, this happens when go back from that activity and come again, list.size() is returning 1 and an item is remaing ,i don't know if it is loading from cache object instance here is my code of adapter class

[please look to the image attached ,list is empty but still counter 1 counter = cartModelList.size()]i have a list of cart items`private List<CartModel> cartModelList;`

It's returning `null` on app fresh install which is good but when i add item to the cart and then remove all the items then its returning 1.

I mean `cartmodelList.size()` is returning as far I know it's returning some items from cached objects or some thing like that.

> The question is how to remove that List object cached or any alternative?

I tried on delete button but still cached coming

```java
    public static  double p = 0;
    private List<CartModel> cartModelList;
    Database db;
    Context context;

    public CartAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModelList) {
        this.cartModelList = cartModelList;
        this.context = context;
        db = new Database(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_layout_item, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Viewholder holder, final int position) {


        String namee = cartModelList.get(position).getName();
        String manufacturere = cartModelList.get(position).getManufacturer();
        String availabilitye = cartModelList.get(position).getAvailability();
        String e_parte = cartModelList.get(position).getE_part();
        String m_parte = cartModelList.get(position).getM_part();
        String floatprice = cartModelList.get(position).getUnit_();
        String int_quantity = cartModelList.get(position).getQuantity();
        String float_line_total = cartModelList.get(position).getLine_total();



        holder.setItemDetails(namee, manufacturere, availabilitye, e_parte, m_parte, floatprice, int_quantity, float_line_total);


        int  checker = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).cartcount().getCounter();

        if (checker <= 0){

            cartModelList.clear();

        }

        holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (db.deleteProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID())) {

                        cartModelList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product  deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product not deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                CartList user111 = new CartList(--COUNTER_BADGE);

                //  Toast.makeText(context, "else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).cartList(user111);
                ((Activity)context).invalidateOptionsMenu();
                ((Activity)context).finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }



        });


 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartModelList.size();
    }

    class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;
        private TextView manufacturer;
        private TextView availability;
        private TextView e_part;
        private TextView m_part;
        private TextView price;
        private EditText quantity;
        private TextView linetotal;
        private Button btn_delete;
        private Button btn_update;
        private  Button adapter_livestock;
        public  SpinKitView progressbar;

        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            manufacturer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
            availability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.availability);
            e_part = itemView.findViewById(R.id.e_part);
            m_part = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_part);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            linetotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linetotal);
            btn_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            btn_update = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
            adapter_livestock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_livestock);
            progressbar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapterrprogresslivestockprogress);

        }


        private void setItemDetails(String namee, String manufacturere, String availabilitye, String e_parte, String m_parte, String floatprice, String int_quantity, String float_line_total) {

            name.setText(namee);
            manufacturer.setText(manufacturere);
            availability.setText(availabilitye);
            e_part.setText(e_parte);
            m_part.setText(m_parte);
            price.setText("£"+floatprice);
            quantity.setText(int_quantity);
            linetotal.setText("£"+float_line_total);


        }


    }
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxDTZ.jpg]

Comment: Do you have only one variable with name "cartModelList"? maybe you have one local and another one in class?

Comment: @OlegSkidan i have that list initialised inside class like global, and the rest are in function in this class ,like cartModelList.get(position).getName(); inside a function

Comment: can you show us more code, please?

Comment: @OlegSkidan i have added more code and an image to the question please see

Comment: So, you delete last item or clear the list. Do you ask about why your toolbar cart badge shows 1 item?

Comment: @OlegSkidan there is some cached data so that's why cartModelList.size() is returning one ,

Comment: @OlegSkidan i think one cart item is in cached because all the items are adding except one ,i put condition item can be added once after that only update the values .

Comment: @OlegSkidan how can i remove that cache ,or any other soloution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved by putting cartModelList.clear on delete button when cartModelList.size() == 1 , so after deleting the last item it will clear the list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... The first.

```
if (db.deleteProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID()))
```

will not delete your item from cartModelList, you need to do it manually. Like this:

```
if (db.deleteProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID())) {
    cartModelList.remove(position)
```

And the second. You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() or itemChanged or itemRemoved etc. only in the end of your deletion method. Please, tell me, if it worked.

P.S. Your items do not cached. The problem is in your code order.

Edit 1. Also, you need to check your `db.deleteProduct` method. Is it worked? Is your if statement worked?

Edit 2. Try this.

```
holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (db.deleteProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID())) {
                    cartModelList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Product  deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Product not deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            CartList user111 = new CartList(cartModelList.size());

            //  Toast.makeText(context, "else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).cartList(user111);
            ((Activity)context).invalidateOptionsMenu();
            ((Activity)context).finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i alredy added  cartModelList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();   on delete button clicklistener please see in question

Comment: did it helped? can you put the breakpoint  in line `CartList user111 = new CartList(cartModelList.size());`?

Comment: you are giving me soloutions that i already it in my question code

Comment: @shahid see the difference in `CartList user111 = new CartList(cartModelList.size());`

Comment: at first i tried that that's not working so i moved on to this one

Comment: so i put the breakpoint it is returning 3 when there is three item and 1 when there is one item and so on  but when there is no item i mean recyclerview is empty so the adapter class is not even executed and the cartlist size is 1 which i get from shared prefrences as you can see in the image

Comment: I see, but your list is empty, when you delete last item. Maybe problem in your preference service...